# Software for Linux Server using K3s to view logs in a nice way?

Tags: linux, logs

The current logs are unformatted and looks very cluttered.

Is there a software for Linux where I can view the logs properly and clearly without the clutter? No gaps, no spacing, no new lines and what not.